# how to install missing jars in eclipse for aws sdk with SES service

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, amazon-web-services

I added maven set up to my eclipse project and I am able to see the lib in my target folder,
I referred the AWS SES docs to send mail using API .  I wont see any complation error but when I try to send mail usig AWS SES API I am getting class not found exception .

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.pool.ConnPoolControl

After  searching on google I added jars (both with mavan and Java build path ) ,Both of the ways doesnt work out.

I am unable to find out the exact problem .
 my maven code includes .

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.9.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-hal-client-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I can able import all class specified in doc,but whenever i call email sending method I getting class not found exception .

I have
 1.Eclipse Helios
 2. Spring-hibernate project
3.Maven 2

and I have access and secret key for AWS set up

Please some one help me out .

I encountered the following error:

```
    Sep 01, 2014 4:18:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/peer] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/pool/ConnPoolControl] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.pool.ConnPoolControl
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1713)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2888)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1172)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
    at com.amazonaws.http.ConnectionManagerFactory.createPoolingClientConnManager(ConnectionManagerFactory.java:29)
    at com.amazonaws.http.HttpClientFactory.createHttpClient(HttpClientFactory.java:97)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:181)
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:119)
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:103)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient.<init>(AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient.java:142)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient.<init>(AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient.java:123)
```